# Meaning of sentences - Harry Potter

Tags: sentence-meaning

> He hurried to his car and set off for home, hoping he was imagining things, which he had never hoped before, because he didn't approve of imagination.

Can you please explain the meaning of this. Especially the last portion  "**because he didn't approve of imagination.**"

Answer (score 4):

Mr. Dursley had never before hoped that he was imagining things, because he regarded imagination as something improper—presumably because it distracts one from important Real things like Money and Status.